# Error: Cannot convert undefined value to object error

Tags: react-native, google-vision

I am working through various tutorials using React Native that involve setting up the Vision API e.g.:

https://davidl.fr/blog/google-vision-with-react-native

However, I am receiving a "error cannot convert undefined value to object" message when I run the code and upload an image on Expo Go.

Is there a way to tell if I have set up the API correctly or is this error due to the react-native code?

Thanks!

Error caused by the callGoogleVisionAsync

```
async function callGoogleVisionAsync(image) {
  const body = {
    requests: [
      {
        image: {
          content: image,
        },
        features: [
          {
            type: 'LABEL_DETECTION',
            maxResults: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

Comment: What is the `image` that you're passing to this function? Be sure it's not `undefined`.

Comment: Hi Nima, thanks for the reply! It's an image taken by the iphone and stored on the disk. Cheers, John.